# Angular 6 - Return value on http error

Tags: angular, http, try-catch, httpclient, return-value

i'm trying to protect my routes by implementing an asynchronous guard. To do so, I've created an AuthService with a method called isUserLoggedIn that consumes information from an API.

auth.service.ts

```
isUserLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.get<HttpApiResponse>(AppSettings.API_ENDPOING + 'auth/test').pipe(
      map(response => response.data.logged)
    );
  }
```

And I have a guard  that uses the service, if the user is logged in, the access is denied, but if the user is not logged in the access is granted.

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) { }

    canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.auth.isUserLoggedIn().pipe(
      retry(3),
      map(response => !response)
    );
  }
}
```

By here, everything is working properly. Now what I need is to grant the access to the user when the API is not responding or responds with error codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch a http error with the `catchError` operator and handle the error accordingly.

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) { }

    canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | 
Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.auth.isUserLoggedIn().pipe(
      retry(3),
      map(response => !response),
      catchError(err => {
        // handle error, check error code and return true or 
             false
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As SplitterAlex told me, I used the catchError inside pipe to handle the error as follows.

```
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.auth.isUserLoggedIn().pipe(
      retry(3),
      map(response => !response),
      catchError(error => {
        return of(true);
      })
    );
  }
```

An important thing here was to import ***of*** from 'rxjs' to be able to return true or false inside the catchError.

Comment: Do you mind accept my answer as vaild answer? I think it helped you :) Thank you